# How to expand awk variables within the code?

Tags: awk

Assuming that i passed some variables to the awk script:

```
$AWK -f script.awk -v var01="foo" var02="bar"
```

And inside the script i obtain some pattern:

```
# pattern01 var01
/pattern01/ {
        if (??? == "foo") print
}
```

I want to expand the variable "$2" ("var01") to its given value.
I have been trying with gawk and it seems to be able to expand variables in the following way:

```
print $$x
```

But this, for some reason, doesn't work in the first example, also i need to keep POSIX compatibility. Is it possible to expand the variable in the given example?
(Note: I want specifically this behavior (if possible), so i don't want workarounds with other tools or shell expansion)

Equivalent in shell:

```
file01:
        foobar
        some random text
        pattern01 var01
        more random text...

code.sh:
        #!/bin/sh
        var01="Hello"
        x="$(grep '^pattern01' file01 | awk '{print $2}')"
        eval echo "$"$x # prints Hello
```

Comment: because i am printing the found pattern, which in the given example would be "pattern01 var01": $1="pattern01", $2="var01"

Comment: @MayAccer, is `var02` a shell variable? Could you please provide more information on this one please.

Comment: "var02" is a variable defined by the flag "-v", then the awk script is called to process some file, this file may have some pattern followed by the string "var01/var02", i want to transform that string in the variable with same name. (i will edit and add the equivalent in shell script)

Comment: Just use the variable by its name just like you would in C, etc. e.g. `print var01`.

Comment: The content of the variable should be printed if, and only if, it appears inside some pattern, so i will have its name only after obtaining some pattern

Comment: Using variable in `awk` see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script/19075707#19075707

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using POSIX awk, there is no way to lookup the value of a variable by it's name. Instead consider using an array to store the values. Not the most elegant, but portable:

$AWK -e 'BEGIN { v["var01"] = "foo" ; v["var02"] = "bar" }' -f script.awk

script.awk

```
# pattern01 var01
/pattern01/ {
        if ( v[$2] == "foo") print
}
```

If you know that you will be new GNU AWK version, and OK with using extensions, you can use the SYMTAB array. From man page:

> SYMTAB      An  array whose indices are the names of all currently
>   defined global variables and arrays in the program.  The array may be
>                      used for indirect access to read or write the value of a variable:
>
> ```
>   foo = 5
>   SYMTAB["foo"] = 4
>   print foo    # prints 4
> ```

```
$AWK -f script.awk -v var01="foo" var02="bar"

script.awk
# pattern01 var01
/pattern01/ {
        if ( SYMTAB[$2] == "foo") print
}
```

Both approached eliminate the need to create environment variables, which may have impact on other programs, and may be hard to scale.

Comment: As i expected a dictionary is the only portable (at least from what i have tested) solution. In my case the environment is cleaned, but this solution is less error prone, so i will mark as better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one solution, by setting the variable as part of the environment and then calling the special variable "ENVIRON" with the name (as it acts as a dictionary):

```
# pattern01 var01
/pattern01/ {
        if (ENVIRON[$2] == "foo") print
}
```

I think that by creating manually the dictionary at the BEGIN stage, the same behaviour could be achieved without making use of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
var01="Hello"
x="$(grep '^pattern01' file01 | awk '{print $2}')"
echo ${!x}
```

hope this helps..
Thanks,

Comment: Would work in shell script (specifically bash),  and in a better way than using "eval". But the problem weren't to achieve this behaviour in shell script